# Можно сказать "дисбаланс серотонина"?

Tags: лексика, грамматика, правила

Не правильней ли формулировка "дефицит серотонина"? Ведь баланс - это соотношение нескольких компонентов.

Comment: "Дефицит" (а по-русски "недостаток") звучит логичнее, но если речь идёт действительно о недостатке. Ведь под "дисбалансом" автор может подразумевать и избыток.

Answer (score 2):

Прежде всего, баланс — равновесие, уравновешивание. Балансировать — держать равновесие. Также используется в значении правильного соотношения компонентов.

Дисбаланс — это нарушение правильного соотношения (баланса) компонентов какого-либо процесса или действия. Это может быть как недостаток (дефицит), так и переизбыток (профицит). То есть дефицит — это только половина.

Ещё один, но менее вероятный вариант:
Дисбаланс — нарушение функционирования чего-нибудь, связей между кем-чем-либо.
Серотонин называют гормоном хорошего настроения или гормоном счастья.
То есть этот гормон в организме плохо функционирует.